# How to call a function on change of window.checkoutConfig data so to refresh the content of checkout page Magento 2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2, checkout, knockout-2.0

In my checkout page when `promo code` is applied, I am updating a text using some calculation in knockoutjs

So, I am using `window.checkoutConfig` data in my js for some calculation.
the function works well when called from HTML, but it doesn't run on itself when `window.checkoutConfig` data is changed, I need to reload the page to see my changes.
And this is what knockoutjs is for, Automatic UI Refresh.

> Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
 <span class="tag-text">
    <!-- ko if: getFinalSale($parent)-->
      <u class="product-tag underline-bold-text checkout-final-sale" data-bind="text: getFinalSale($parent)"></u>
    <!-- /ko -->
</span>
```

I have written above code in details.html

and my js is

> Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js

knockout js

```
  define([
   'uiComponent',
   'ko',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ], function (Component, ko, totals) {
   'use strict';
    var finalSaleData = window.checkoutConfig.items;

    return Component.extend({
     defaults: {
         template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
     },
    quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
    finalSaleData: finalSaleData,

    /**
     * @param {Object} quoteItem
     * @return {String}
     */

    getItems: function(item_id) {
        var itemElement = null;
        _.each(this.finalSaleData, function(element, index) {
            if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                itemElement = element;
            }
        });
        return itemElement;
    },
    getFinalSale: function (quoteItem) {
        var item = this.getItems(quoteItem.item_id);
        var tagText = '';

        if((((item.price*item.qty) - item.discount_amount)/(item.base_old_price*item.qty))< 0.5){
            var tagText = 'Final Sale';
        }else{
            if(item.base_old_price && item.price){
                // && item.price < item.price && item.base_old_price / item.price <= 0.5){
                if(((item.base_old_price - item.price)/item.base_old_price)>0.5){
                    var tagText = 'Final Sale';
                }
            }
        }
        return tagText;
    },   
  });
});
```

I am using `var finalSaleData = window.checkoutConfig.items` in my function `getFinalSale`.

How to make `getFinalSale` function run every time when `window.checkoutConfig.items` data is changed without refreshing the page.

The problem is, this runs only when the page reloads.

How to make `getFinalSale` function run every time the user applies `promo code` without refreshing the page so that my HTML gets updated too.

Basically `Final Sale` text needs to be shown on the basis of that logic in js code in `getFinalSale` function.

How to achieve that.

Comment: could create a code snippet to run this problem code ? if u want to do with some value changes, so you need declare ko.observable and ko.computed to achieve that, please make snippet i will have a look at this.